# Hooks with use-package and `ado-mode` not working

Tags: hooks, use-package

I'm trying to apply hooks to `ado-mode` a mode for working with the propietary software for statirstical analysis stata. However, the following doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

```lisp
  (use-package ado-mode
     :hook
      (ado-mode  . display-line-numbers-mode)
      (ado-mode  . inactivate-default-input-method))
```

Using `:custom` instead of `:hook` doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that `ado-mode` actually defines `ado-mode-hook`? Do `C-h v <RET> ado-mode-hook<RET>` when the mode is loaded to find out.

Comment: You have the wrong format after hook, please fix it first

Comment: Thank you for the feeback! @Wang, what do you mean by the wrong format? Is it not `whatever-mode . foo` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn on minor mode rainbow-mode using use-package](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/turn-on-minor-mode-rainbow-mode-using-use-package)