# Turn on minor mode rainbow-mode using use-package

Tags: hooks, use-package

I would like to turn on [rainbow-mode](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/rainbow-mode.html) in elisp and/or lisp modes when I am editing `init.el` using `use-package`. I've tried the following:

```
(use-package rainbow-mode
  :demand t
  :hook 
  ((text-mode  . rainbow-mode)
   (elisp-mode . rainbow-mode)
   (lisp-mode  . rainbow-mode)))
```

I've also tried attacking it from the other side and attaching it to the lisp/elisp mode definition

```
(use-package lisp-mode
  :ensure nil
  :hook 
  (lisp-mode  . rainbow-mode))
```

And I also tried using a setup method:

```
(use-package elisp-mode
  :ensure nil
  :hook 
   (elisp-mode  . lisp-mode-setup))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I can turn it on manually in the buffer by calling `M-x rainbow-mode` but I can't get `use-package` to play ball. I'm basically trying to find a way to add code to a mode hook.

What am I missing? Should I do this a different way? Am I hooking into the correct mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(use-package rainbow-mode
  :hook (emacs-lisp-mode text-mode lisp-mode))
```

---

This is from the `use-package` info manual

**File**: `use-package.info`,  **Node**: `hook`

`:hook`

The `:hook` keyword allows adding functions onto hooks, here only the
basename of the hook is required.  Thus, all of the following are
equivalent:

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :hook prog-mode)
```

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :hook (prog-mode . ace-jump-mode))
```

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :commands ace-jump-mode
       :init
       (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
```

And likewise, when multiple hooks should be applied, the following
are also equivalent:

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :hook (prog-mode text-mode))
```

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :hook ((prog-mode text-mode) . ace-jump-mode))
```

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :hook ((prog-mode . ace-jump-mode)
         (text-mode . ace-jump-mode)))
```

```lisp
     (use-package ace-jump-mode
       :commands ace-jump-mode
       :init
       (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode)
       (add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
```

The use of `:hook`, as with `:bind`, `:mode`, `:interpreter`, etc.,
causes the functions being hooked to implicitly be read as `:commands`
(meaning they will establish interactive `autoload` definitions for that
module, if not already defined as functions), and so `:defer t` is also
implied by `:hook`.